# Creating multiple windows in SWT

Tags: java, swt

I'm trying to create a `Window` class which I can use to open multiple windows, and which will automatically add an event handler to listen for the `Swt.CLOSE` event, and call the `shell.dispose()` method when it is called.

My questions are:

1. Do I need to listen for `shell.dispose()` in this case, or to only listen for `display.dispose()` in my main method?
2. Do I need to run each window in its own thread, or can all the windows share the same UI thread? I've read some reports of buggy behavior related to event handling in case of multiple windows being open.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I recommend you should *always* have a single UI thread, which the single `Display` object runs on. See [SWT: single vs. multiple displays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4421075/swt-single-vs-multiple-displays) or even the [Eclipse documentation on Display](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/swt/widgets/Display.html) that strongly recommends using a single `Display` object:

> Applications which are built with SWT will *almost always* require only a single display. In particular, some platforms which SWT supports will not allow more than one *active* display.

There are even several sample apps available (such as [this one](http://www.chrisnewland.com/swt-best-practice-single-display-multiple-shells-111)) that demonstrate multiple shells in SWT.  Calling `shell.dispose()` when you want to close a window is the way to go.

You should only use `display.dispose()` when you are shutting down the entire app, basically as a 'last step' - see [this](http://git.eclipse.org/c/platform/eclipse.platform.swt.git/tree/examples/org.eclipse.swt.snippets/src/org/eclipse/swt/snippets/Snippet1.java) example, or [this](http://git.eclipse.org/c/platform/eclipse.platform.swt.git/tree/examples/org.eclipse.swt.snippets/src/org/eclipse/swt/snippets/Snippet108.java) one, or pretty much any snippet on the [SWT Snippets page](http://www.eclipse.org/swt/snippets/).

**Edit**

The Eclipse framework itself is an example of an application that can have multiple windows - it still uses a single `Display`, with a single UI Thread and shared event system. [Eclipse documentation on Threading Issues](http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/guide/swt_threading.htm) has a basic explanation of this:

> Underneath any GUI application, regardless of its language or UI toolkit, the OS platform detects GUI events and places them in application event queues. [...] It determines which window and application should receive each event and places it in the application's event queue.

Comment: If I have multiple windows open, can they all handle their own event navigation if they're using the same Display and thread?

Comment: See Edit, which should address this

Comment: If you're looking to disallow multiple windows from being able to fire events at the same time and would prefer to act modally, you need to use SWT.APPLICATION_MODAL to force the windows to act in a modal fashion.  I believe that the default is allowing every window to act independently and handle their own event navigation.